# Order of multi column index and SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, indexing

I found two contrary statements regarding the order of multi column indexes in MySQL.
This post [here](http://www.ovaistariq.net/17/mysql-indexes-multi-column-indexes-and-order-of-columns/) has in the comments that an (a, b) index would also be used for a query with (b = value1 AND a = value2). This FAQ entry [here](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Indexes/When-does-multi-column-index-come-into-use-in-MySQL) says (on the bottom) exactly the opposite (index won't be used). What is correct? And how about PostgreSQL? Does it behave the same way?

Comment: I'm no mySQL expert (just SQL Server and a bit Oracle), but that FAQ answer look *very* fishy to me (full table scan *three* times because of three conditions in the WHERE? Puuhlease!). Every decent SQL system will use the composite index for that kind of query (except when the table is so small that it doesn't pay to use the index at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me say, there is no silver bullet answer.

And index on (a,b) composite index will be used to satisfy a query (b=value1 and a=value2). Note that it does **not** matter that "b" is presented before "a" in the WHERE clause, since the query engine knows you are dealing with both a and b.  It STILL may not be used if the selectivity is not high enough.

Having said that

```
2. [SELECT * FROM buyers WHERE last_name=? AND first_name=? AND zip=?]
can't use the index.
```

That has to top my unbelievable-faq-entry find for today.  It is partially right, and only because the `SELECT *` requires a lookup back to the table so any benefit from the composite index is halved (or further minimized).  Compare the two queries at the end of this code instead

```
CREATE TABLE buyers(
 buyer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 first_name CHAR(19) NOT NULL,
 last_name CHAR(19) NOT NULL,
 zip CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 state_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (buyer_id)
 );

insert buyers values
(991,'zeshan ','Nadeem ',92082,'CA'),
(992,'Ken ','Marcus ',92082,'CA'),
(993,'Tariq ','Iqbal ',92082,'CA'),
(994,'Tariq ','Iqbal ',92082,'CA'),
(995,'Hasnat ','Ahmad ',92083,'NY'),
(996,'Tariq ','Iqbal ',92082,'DC'),
(997,'Keith ','Worlf ',93083,'NG'),
(998,'Ashley ','Lewis ',92088,'NJ'),
(999,'Tariq ','Mehmood ',99088,'TX');

ALTER TABLE buyers ADD INDEX idx_firstname (first_name);
ALTER TABLE buyers ADD INDEX idx_last_name (last_name);
ALTER TABLE buyers ADD INDEX idx_zip (zip);
ALTER TABLE buyers ADD INDEX idx_flname_zip(first_name,last_name,zip);
```

Run this in a separate query

```
explain
SELECT first_name,last_name,zip FROM buyers WHERE first_name='Tariq' AND last_name='Iqbal' AND zip=92082;
```

And then this

```
explain
SELECT last_name,first_name,zip FROM buyers WHERE last_name='Iqbal' AND first_name='Tariq' AND zip=92082;
```

They will show the same plan